# onClientClick not working when calling a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, onclientclick

I want to trigger a jQuery form display when a user clicks on an ASP.NET server-side button.

However when I click on the button at runtime, the page just reloads really quick .. No jQuery form opening ..

The effect I'm trying to create can be seen here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/khSxK/3/)

Basically I want to open the same dialog box when someone clicks on the ASP.NET button ..

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<asp:Button ID="createuser" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick='$("#dialogform").dialog("open");'/>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $( "#dialogform" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 450,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          alert('Hello');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

I have also tried using `jQuery` instead of the `$` identifier to call jQuery functions. And I've also tried to remove the `onClientClick` event, and tried using this code instead for the script block above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $( "#dialogform" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 450,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          alert('Hello');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    });

    $( "#createuser" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialogform" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });

</script>
```

Can anyone identify what's the problem ?

Comment: Is it opening the dialog or not? what it gives? Did you check browser console?

Comment: Does not open the dialog .. Only reloads the page real quick ..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using

```
<asp:Button ID="createuser" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick='$("#dialogform").dialog("open");'/>
```

try using

```
<input type='button' value="Button"  onclick='$("#dialogform").dialog("open");' />
```

Comment: Not working .. First gave me an error on the `$` symbol .. When I switched to `jQuery` it started giving me the `) expected` error .. And I've checked .. there are no missing parenthesis .. Besides, `OnClick` is only used for server-side functions I think ..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

*If you're referring directly to the control on the server side, ClientID should including any NamingContainer information (from something like a GridView or a Repeater or anywhere else). Find out what the client ID of the control is using your browser's developer tools (IE has Developer Tools, Firebug for Firefox, etc.), then debug JavaScript.*

```
function  DoStuff() {
     $( "#dialogform" ).dialog( "open" );
     return false;
 });


<asp:LinkButton id="createuser" OnClientClick="DoStuff();" runat="server">
```

Comment: Not really needed though as I'm using `onClientClick` on the server-side button to call the client-side JavaScript function .. Not the other way around ..

Comment: Then which function you are calling `onclientClick()`?

Comment: Yup, I'm using `onClientClick` to call the JavaScript function .. This can be seen from my code above as well ..

Comment: There is no such a function you have created to be executed by clicking `onClientClick()`. you posted code executes on DOM Ready only not `onClientClick()`. Check Documentation for jQuery first

Answer (score 0):

Your button is likely posting back to the server, and you need to prevent that like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="createuser" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick='$("#dialogform").dialog("open"); return false;'/>
```

If the html input mentioned above by Swapnil was throwing an error on the '$', then it sounds like jQuery is either not loaded, or the '$' was taken over by something else.  I'd use your browser's developer tools to see if jQuery is being downloaded.  In IE, do F12, go to the Network tab, click the "Start capturing" button, refresh your page, then check the row with jQuery.